# Cleaning old UITableViewCells while navigating back and forth

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two `UITableViewController` and I use navigation controller to go back from view#2 to view#1 .

In the first view I select some values from `UIPickerView` then by a button touch it will go to the second view and the the second view show some cells according to the `UIPicker` selection from view#1 , and here comes my problem when I go back to first view and change the selection of UiPicker and press the button to go to the second view I will find the old cells there for just a second until my view#2 get reload the new data inside this function

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I tried to remove the data from all arrays and reload again with empty data trying to remove the old cells like this :

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        arra1=[]
        arra2=[]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and here my code that passing the data from view#1 to view#2:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "MySegue") {

        let destinationVC:onCallEmployee = segue.destinationViewController as! onCallEmployee


        if self.selectedDeptIndex != 0 {
        destinationVC.previewsViewData.append(String(self.selectedDeptIndex))
        }
        if self.teamsIdByName[selectedTeamName] != nil{
        destinationVC.previewsViewData.append(self.teamsIdByName[selectedTeamName]!)
        }
        if self.servicesIdByName[selectedServiceName] != nil {
        destinationVC.previewsViewData.append(self.servicesIdByName[selectedServiceName]!)
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any way to clean the view#2 before going back to view#1?

Comment: How are you sharing the data between those 2 views?

Comment: @ricardopereira I added the code to the question

Comment: Add code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `destinationViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
```

instead of this:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I'm happy for you. Good job

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading your table in

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Do that in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I use reloadData() in viewWillAppear I'll have nothing on my view#2

Comment: That should not be the case, please try printing your `dataSource` array before calling `reloadData()` see if you have data in that. Also tell me what if you are using a **ViewController** or **TableViewController**

Comment: using TableViewController , and let me try what you said

Comment: when I try to print before reloadData() I get : Array index out of range

Comment: I will check this procedure and let you know. Because technically this should not happen.

Comment: yes  I know I saw a lot of answers saying same you did but didn't work for me , but really thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problems with stale data in `UITableViewCells` usually indicate that you need to properly implement `prepareForReuse` in the cell to completely clear out old cell data.

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    myTextCell.text = ""
}
```

`prepareForReuse` will get called just before a recycled cell is returned from `UITableView.dequeueCell...`

Comment: Thank you , still not working , but if I don't use self.tableView.reloadData() inside viewDidAppear sometimes I get nothing when I press the button to view#2 where I must have data , is the problem by passing the data ?